# python plotting change background color and line color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

This [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data) has a tutorial that shows how to plot different metrics for test and training data by epochs. Please check the output of `plot_metrics(baseline_history)`

I only have two metrics to print
I copied the plotting part and need help with below

1. How to change color of test line to red? I tried `plt.plot(history.epoch, history.history['val_'+metric],
            color=colors['r'], linestyle="--", label='Val')` But got the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
2. how to ensure the plain background. For some reason I am getting
   grey color background with white lines

my code and output below

```
#plotting
def plot_metrics(history):
  metrics =  ['loss','acc']
  for n, metric in enumerate(metrics):
    name = metric.replace("_"," ").capitalize()
    plt.subplot(2,2,n+1)
    plt.plot(history.epoch,  history.history[metric], color=colors[0], label='Train')
    plt.plot(history.epoch, history.history['val_'+metric],
             color=colors[9], linestyle="--", label='Val')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel(name)
    if metric == 'loss':
      plt.ylim([0, plt.ylim()[1]])
    elif metric == 'auc':
      plt.ylim([0.8,1])
    else:
      plt.ylim([0,1])

    plt.legend()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 12)
plot_metrics(final_model)#where abcde is fit call
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can simply try adding the color parameter.
   Usage: plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6], color='red')
2. You can use grid(False) to remove the grid.
   usage: plt.grid(False)